# How to do a batch insert in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert

I have 1-many number of records that need to be entered into a table.  What is the best way to do this in a query?  Should I just make a loop and insert one record per iteration?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: Please read the documentation for a statement or function before attempting to use it. [`INSERT` supports this natively](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)!

Comment: If you have a really large number of records and could format them as a CSV file, check out the LOAD DATA INFILE statement or mysqlimport command.

Comment: For the record, [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) is a very flexible command that does not *require* CSV input; any text format will do, and there are a number of helpful parameters for parsing and manipulating input data. This is definitely the *fastest* way to load data into a local db. It's not clear what is meant by "best" above: i.e. whether simplicity (use INSERT statements) trumps speed (use LOAD DATA).

Answer (score 384, accepted):

From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)

> INSERT statements that use VALUES
>   syntax can insert multiple rows. To do
>   this, include multiple lists of column
>   values, each enclosed within
>   parentheses and separated by commas.
>   Example:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

Comment: Is this slower than Load Data Infile?

Comment: what is syntax to write this insert statement in stored procedure?

Comment: @Nitin wouldn't it be the same syntax..???  That's what I would do in SQL Server anyway.

Comment: Please note that while the question is labelled "How to do *batch* inserts" this answer is actually *bulk* insert. Bulk is usually faster, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389449/performance-of-mysql-insert-statements-in-java-batch-mode-prepared-statements-v)

Comment: SQL Server limits number of rows per insert to 1,000. Does MySQL have a limit?

Comment: Do you know how many values you can insert in one go? What if I have 10,000 VALUES blocks?

Comment: @Koffeehaus Per [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3536148/1554982) from @Lukman, number of values/rows that can be inserted is limited by [`max_allowed_packet`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)

Answer (score 27):

Most of the time, you are not working in a MySQL client and you should batch inserts together using the appropriate API.

E.g. in JDBC:

```
connection con.setAutoCommit(false); 
PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE DEPT SET MGRNO=? WHERE DEPTNO=?");
prepStmt.setString(1,mgrnum1);                 
prepStmt.setString(2,deptnum1);
prepStmt.addBatch();

prepStmt.setString(1,mgrnum2);                        
prepStmt.setString(2,deptnum2);
prepStmt.addBatch();

int [] numUpdates=prepStmt.executeBatch();
```

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/tjvbtupd.htm

Comment: A good blog entry on batch inserts (in Java, but it's relevant to any language):

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/

Comment: Even though this is an example, it's probably a good idea turn auto commit on again after executing the batch. Might also be useful to briefly why it is useful as well (can improve performance for batches). Oh wow just realised how old this q/q is.

Answer (score 11):

```
Insert into table(col1,col2) select col1,col2 from table_2;
```

Please refer to [MySQL documentation on INSERT Statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Comment: how about `insert into select from ` performance? is it as fast as bulk insert?

Answer (score 11):

Load data infile query is much better option but some servers like godaddy restrict this option on shared hosting so , only two options left then one is insert record on every iteration or batch insert , but batch insert has its limitaion of characters if your query exceeds this number of characters set in mysql then your query will crash , So I suggest insert data in chunks withs batch insert , this will minimize number of connections established with database.best of luck guys

Comment: How about `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/users/name/txt.file'`

Answer (score 2):

mysql allows you to insert multiple rows at once [INSERT manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO test_1 VALUES(24, 'B', '1990-12-07'), (25, 'C', '1990-12-08');

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32305466)