# Is it possible to create Batch insert?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

i just started discovering serviceStack ORMlite , and i am trying to figure out how to do batch inserts. Are there any example of this anywhere ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's currently no built-in support take take advantage of custom RDBMS's support for this feature. E.g. [MySQL's Batch Insert support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526917/how-to-do-a-batch-insert-in-mysql).

The `Insert` and `InsertAll` methods in OrmLite do already accept multiple entities, but they're executed individually.

Depending on the database (that support batch insert via SQL) you can execute custom arbitrary SQL by using `IDbCommand.ExecuteSql` method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , i am testing ORMLite with SQLite currently , and after some tests , i see that using transactions allows huge improvments. And as you said , using direct SQL can always be done. Thats a very good Data Framework :-)