# Looking for code customisation

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Im using the following php for loop to insert array values in database. I need correction to my code.I want to query out side the for loop.Please help me in correcting my code.

```
<?php
             /*********************/
             $data = $_REQUEST['columns_one'];
             $store_data = explode(",",$data);
            foreach($store_data as $key =>$value)
            {
            //echo $value;
            $query = "insert into fb_savedforms(form_id,form_structure) values ('','".$value."')";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            } 
            /**************************************/
        ?>
```

Comment: You need to phrase your question better. What exactly is or isnt happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$data = $_REQUEST['columns_one'];
$store_data = explode(",",$data);
//setup the insert query
$query = "INSERT INTO fb_savedforms(form_id,form_structure) VALUES ";
$values = array(); //store all the new rows
foreach($store_data as $key =>$value){
  $values[] = "('','".$value."')";
}
$query .=  implode(',', $values) . ';';
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

**Big Disclaimer**: This code has not been tested, but should illustrate that you can have multiple value sets.

Comment: I have tested the code.Its working...Thanks @Tim

Answer (score 1):

Use batch insert to build your query in the loop, but only execute it once.

From [How to do a batch insert in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526917/how-to-do-a-batch-insert-in-mysql)

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within parentheses and separated by commas.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$data = $_REQUEST['columns_one'];
             $store_data = explode(",",$data);
            $query = '';
            foreach($store_data as $key =>$value)
            {
            //echo $value;
            $query .= "insert into fb_savedforms(form_id,form_structure) values ('','".$value."'); ";

            } 
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: You're just going to end up with a string of insert statements like this. This is exactly why batch insert exists.