# How to import data from Excel and remove duplicates using PHP

Tags: php, excel, import

I want to upload thousand of data through excel sheet in table and many column in excel sheet.

I want check all data remove duplicate value also no one can remove imported data only remove duplicate. And also check tables all data.

```
ID  NAME  GIVENNAME  SURNAME  ADDRESS AREA  ZONE  OFFICE  CITY TEHSIL STATE MOBILE ECT...
1   XXX   XXXX       XXXX     XXX     XXX   XXX   XXXX    XXX  XXX    XXX   12345  ...
2   AAA   AAAA       AAAA     AAA     AAA   AAA   AAAA    AAA  AAA    AAA   67890  ...
3   SSS   SSSS       SSSS     SSS     SSS   SSS   SSSS    SSS  SSS    SSS   12345  ...
```

Thank you..

Comment: What do you assume as duplicate value? A single column like `mobile`, or?

Comment: Not a single value is duplicate but one row are duplicate then remove this record because husband's wife is used own husband mobile so mobile number is used more than one time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PHPExcel Library](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to import data from excel. Have for loop which will iterate over the rows.Concatenate data of all column or required columns that you wanted to be unique, create hash for concatenated string.On insertion of new row just check hashes of already inserted rows .if hash found data already inserted else insert current row and update hash array. Store hashes into the array.

Answer (score 0):

use ( LOAD DATA INFILE )
for example I used below Code :
mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE 'addressfile/file.csv' ignore INTO TABLE a FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY ';'");
if you create correct uniq fields in mysql then don't worry about duplicate value.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Jugal's answer, store the hash in an array, but store it in the key field instead of the value field to improve look-up speed (only relevant with really large data-sets).    Then check if the row exists like so:

```
 if(!array_key_exists($hash, $refrenceArray)){
   //it's a duplicate
 } else{
   //it isn't a duplicate so add it to the array
   $refrenceArray[$hash] = 1;    
   //and add the value to your array which is going to the database
   $toDBArray=$rowOfData;
 }
```

Then you'll want to take your array of all the data you've collected ($toDBArray) and do a  [batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526917/how-to-do-a-batch-insert-in-mysql) database insert.

Answer (score -1):

More details youtube :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkphz1WExk8&t=2s
blog :- https://computerstudycs7.blogspot.in/2018/04/how-to-remove-duplicates-in-excel-2007.html

we have list of duplicates values and we are finding the unique values from this data. there are following steps to remove the duplicate data from excel they are following:-

1) First of all open you excel sheet.
2) Select the all data column.
3) Click on the Data tab.
4) Now click on the Remove duplicate data.

Now you have only unique value.