# Building a query string with a multidimentional array

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, string, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build a sql string which can insert multiple row in one query itself please have a look on the following code .
I have an array called

`conversion_rates` which is something like this `array(1) { [11]=> float(507.6) }`

and the code which I am trying to execute is something like this

```
public function updateExRate(){/*Updates the table in the DB with exchange rates*/

    $sql =  'INSERT INTO conversor '.
           '( Sl_no  , Ex_rate,Idmoneda,Time_update) VALUES'.foreach($this->conversion_rates as $k =>$v){.' ( NULL ,'.$v.
           ','.$k.','.time().');'};

    var_dump($this->conversion_rates);
    echo 'Running... '.$sql.'<br>';
    $this->parent->parent->database->query($sql);  

}
```

So this is a function to update the db where i am trying to build a sql statement which is inserting multiple row and to inert the values I am using that foreach  loop inside the string and that is where I am getting the error

Comment: Use mysql batch insert

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526917/how-to-do-a-batch-insert-in-mysql

Comment: I only see JDBC example no php batch example there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO conversor "( Sl_no , Ex_rate,Idmoneda,Time_update) VALUES ';

        foreach($this->conversion_rates as $k =>$v)
        {
            $sql .= '( NULL ,'.$v.','.$k.','.time().');';

        }

        $sql .= '"}';
```

Comment: small mistake in the code :)    $sql = '( NULL ,'.$v.','.$k.','.time().');';                                           it should be  $sql .= '( NULL ,'.$v.','.$k.','.time().');';   I mean '.' was missing because of that the string was being overwritten

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
$sql =  'INSERT INTO conversor ( `Sl_no`  , `Ex_rate,Idmoneda`,`Time_update`) VALUES ';

foreach($this->conversion_rates as $k =>$v)$sql.="( NULL ,'$v','$k',".time()."),";

$sql=rtrim($sql, ",").";";
```

Comment: This is uch better :)