# Insert 100.000 entries to MySQL with tasks - C#

Tags: c#, mysql.data

I am having some troubles with my code. I am trying to insert about 100.000 items in a Mysql table using  Tasks to speed up the process. Here is my code:

```
List < Task > tasks = new List < Task > ();
int counter = 0;
foreach(var folder in dirs) {
    object lockTarget = new object();

    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        try {
                comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO webdata(url,title) VALUES(?sUrl,?sTitle,) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE url=?sUrl,title=?sTitle";
                comm.Parameters.Add("?sUrl", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = url;
                comm.Parameters.Add("?sTitle", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = title;

                var mysql_return = comm.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                lock(lockTarget) {
                    counter++;
                    Console.WriteLine("\rProcessing {0} of {1} - {2} {3}", counter, dirs.Length, folder, mysql_return.Status);
                }

        } catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }    
    }));
}

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    conn.Close();
});
```

So, when i run my code, some of the Tasks (mysql_return) are returning `rantocompletion` and some `Faulted`, thus only 1/2 of my entries actually inserted to the DB.

I could use `ExecuteNonQuery` and no `Task` but it will take ages to insert so many data.
Is the problem due to hardware(CPU can't keep up with thousands of spawned tasks) or due to my code?

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you just insert batch instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526917/how-to-do-a-batch-insert-in-mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem1**: `comm` is modified in multiple threads it seems, that has to be a local variable.

**Problem2**: You're not waiting for the task returned by `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` and thus `Task` returned by `StartNew` will not wait for the completion of the `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` to be finished.

Eventually you close the connection assuming that all are done but they aren't. They all are started, but not completed.

You need to use await the result of `ExecuteNonQueryAsync`(for that use `async` lambda) and also call `Task.UnWrap` or use `Task.Run` which gives you `UnWrap` for free.

So your code will become something like the following:

```
tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => //Note Task.Run and async lambda
 {
      try
      {
        var comm = new WhateverCommand();
        ...

        var mysql_return = await comm.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();//Note the await
        ...
      }
      catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex) 
      {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      }    
}));
```

Comment: @Theodoros80 But remember only if you solve both the problems you can reach success.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a try. Some things are clear to my head now.