# Is there a faster way to import data from a file to MySQL using php?

Tags: php, mysql, splfileobject

Okay, so I get around 100k-1M lines of text that I always import to a database. The code that i use is as follows:

```
$lines = new SplFileObject('/home/file.txt');
while(!$lines->eof()) {
    $lines->next();       //Skipping first line
    $row = explode(',',$lines);
    for($i = 0; $i<4; $i++){
        if(!isset($row[$i])){
            $row[$i] = null;
        }
    }
    $y = (float) $row[1];
    $z = (float) $row[2];
    $load_query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO new (datetime_gmt,field2,field3)
    VALUES ('".$row[0]."','".$y."','".$z."');";

    if(!$mysqli->query($load_query)){
      die("CANNOT EXECUTE".$mysqli->error."\n");
    }
}
$lines = null;
```

However, it takes waaayyy too long. Is there any faster way to do it, or am I stuck with this method?

PS. I don't want to use MySQL's "INSERT DATA INFILE".

Comment: [How to do a batch insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526917/how-to-do-a-batch-insert-in-mysql)

Comment: You just need to read what castis quoted but you should also make the batch limited to 20-50 values(for instance)

Comment: You can write a bulk insert statements in chunks to minimize the number of calls to the database. If you don't care about the order of insertion into the database, then you can use a language that supports threading such as C(++, #), Go, Rust, Java, D, Swift, Scala, etc....

Comment: @castis I'm sorry, i'm struggling to find how would this help. I understand that i can add multiple rows using insert, but how would i do it for 100k rows?

Comment: how do you insert your data to the the database ? after each $load_query ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that, i have edited the code :)

Comment: @AbdallahQaraeen you wouldn't add 100k rows at once, you chunk it up into like 1000 rows or so for each insert.

Comment: @castis Okay, do i manually type those 1000 rows? I'm trying to figure how would i use a for-loop or something similar but i'm unable to. Do you have any suggestions? :)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks for the help. But i have mentioned that i would like to avoid "INSERT DATA INFILE". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, you're running an insert statement for every line. It'll be much faster if you compile a single multi-insert statement in the format of `INSERT INTO table (foo, bar) VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6);` that is executed once at the end. Something along the lines of this, though it could be cleaned up more.

```
$lines = new SplFileObject('/home/file.txt');
$load_query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO new (datetime_gmt,field2,field3)
    VALUES ";
while(!$lines->eof()) {
    $lines->next();       //Skipping first line
    $row = explode(',',$lines);
    for($i = 0; $i<4; $i++){
        if(!isset($row[$i])){
            $row[$i] = null;
        }
    }
    $y = (float) $row[1];
    $z = (float) $row[2];
    $load_query .= "('".$row[0]."','".$y."','".$z."'),";
}

if(!$mysqli->query(rtrim($load_query, ','))) {
    die("CANNOT EXECUTE".$mysqli->error."\n");
}
$lines = null;
```

Also keep make sure the data is trusted. If the file can come from an outside user, appending directly to the query string creates an SQL injection vector.

Comment: yes, multi-inserts will run a lot faster. however, be careful: mysql has a maximum data packet size limit (adjustable on server). make sure your sql statement doesnt reach that limit. For instance do it as 1000 rows at once, then a new insert statement. if you do pass that limit, the sql statement will be corrupt and wont run.

Comment: using a transaction might also help a bit. not as much as multi-inserts tho.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will work. I am though reaching my maximum data packet size and i'm not allowed to increase it. how can i do it as 1000 at once for example, using the code @Zurahn used?

Comment: Nevermind, i fixed it using the seek() function in SplFileObject! Thanks alot! :D