# Mysql 1041 queries limit in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've got a PHP script (mysqli function) which generates `insert into...` queries as an `array of strings` and send them to mysql database one by one. The problem is that there are about 40000 queries and my database always stop inserting new ones after 1041 and soon later close the connection.

Is it a php limitation or problem with mysql? Or maybe something else? How can I avoid this problem and send all queries to database?

Here is the code:

```
        $data // my array of strings - mysql queries

        ini_set ('error_reporting', E_ALL);
        ini_set ('display_errors', '1');
        error_reporting (E_ALL|E_STRICT);

        $connection = mysqli_init();
        mysqli_options ($connection, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);

        mysqli_ssl_set($connection,'/usr/local/certs/client-key.pem',
       '/usr/local/certs/client-cert.pem', '/usr/local/certs/server-ca.pem', NULL, NULL);

        $link = mysqli_real_connect ($connection, $db['host'], $db['user'], $db['password'], 
       $db['dbName'], 3306, NULL,MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT);


        if (!$link)
        {   
            die ('Connect error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . '): ' . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n");
        } 
        else 
        {   

           foreach ($data as $index => $queryToSend) {

                if($connection->query($queryToSend))
                {
                    $this->output->writeln('succesfull query number: '.$index);
                }   
           }



            $connection->close();
        }
```

Comment: Is it possible that your script terminates with the default 30 second time limit?

Comment: You could increase the php.ini settings, time limit or you can divide the job into some pieces.

Comment: Jiri: I don't know is that  the problem because in my terminal mysql process seems to be still working but without adding any new queries. I mean I can only terminate it with ctr/cmd + c button

Comment: @ampher911 What is the error message you get from mysql after the `mysqli_query()` call failed? Also, you should use prepared statements when you run SQL queries with variable inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try batch insertion, this will help you to overcome the problem that you are facing.

Here is a reference
[How to do a batch insert in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526917/how-to-do-a-batch-insert-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Change your default execution time in php file

ini_set('max_execution_time', 120); //120 seconds

I hope this will help.