# Writing CSV to MySql Slow speed

Tags: mysql, csv, pdo

I changed my xls file to csv format for write to MySql. Because I get 60 second timeout error when i tried to save fields from xls file to MySQL. Now when i write `echo` code i am getting all my data in just 5 seconds. But when i try to save it to MySQL 60 second is not enough. Here is my codes:

```
$csvfile = fopen("data.csv","r");
    fgetcsv($csvfile);
    while (($data = fgetcsv($csvfile))!==FALSE){
        $ekle = $dbpdo->prepare("INSERT INTO isletmeler (sno) VALUES ('".$data[0]."')");
        $ekle->execute();   
    }
```

What can i do to speed up the speed of saving data to MySql? I have 29 column in csv but i tried to save just 1 column for see if it save my all data. I have about 2700 fields in csv but it just saving about 1000 fields in 60 second.

Comment: Try to use a batch.

Comment: i didnt understand..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526917/how-to-do-a-batch-insert-in-mysql

Comment: you mean load data inifile?

Comment: if you mean `$ekle = $dbpdo->prepare("INSERT INTO isletmeler (1,2,3,4) VALUES ('1,2,3,4)` i know this.

Comment: No. I mean to load data in larger chunks so you do not have to run `execute()` so many times. Either you can create a batch and add everything to the batch and run it once or you can change the insert statement to insert more data. I mean like `$ekle = $dbpdo->prepare("INSERT INTO isletmeler (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9).....`

Comment: So basically, you will not be calling the `execute()` inside the loop (unless you want to control the batch sizes).

Comment: can you organize my codes for this example?

Comment: you mean like this?
`while (($data = fgetcsv($csvfile))!==FALSE){
 $ekle = $dbpdo->prepare("INSERT INTO isletmeler (sno) VALUES ('".$data[0]."')");
 }
 $ekle->execute();`

Comment: No. That's not what I had in mind. Look at the answer posted. That is using a different approach but should also help with performance significantly.

Answer (score 0):

You could restructure the code so that the prepare is only done once...

```
$csvfile = fopen("data.csv","r");

fgetcsv($csvfile);
$ekle = $dbpdo->prepare("INSERT INTO isletmeler (sno) VALUES (?)");
while (($data = fgetcsv($csvfile))!==FALSE){
    $ekle->execute([$data[0]]);   
}
```

This reduces the need to re-prepare the statement each time.

Comment: i tried your codes. it  saved 774 columns.

Comment: avarage saving in per second is 20 columns.

Comment: hello. I am very sorry but my hosting has a problem for several days. So I couldnt work on your last codes. I am trying to connect every day, every hour. I see that you deleted your last codes? Please write it again.