# Save and update with uniqid in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, gamequery

I tried to insert the player with a unique id in the database.
This model works for me, but if I give it a key update it duplicates it in my database.

**Option 1**

```
$id = uniqid();  
$insert_player_query    = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO players (id,nickname,score,time_online,mapname,sid) VALUES ('$id','$player_nickname','$player_score','$player_time','$mapname','$server_id') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = score + VALUES(score), time_online = time_online + VALUES(time_online) WHERE id='$id'");
```

**Option 2**

Then I tried that, but it doesn't insert anything at all

```
$id = uniqid();  
$sql=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM players WHERE nickname='$player_nickname'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) 
    {
         $insert_player_query2  = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE players (nickname,score,time_online,mapname,sid) VALUES ($player_nickname','$player_score','$player_time','$mapname','$server_id') WHERE id='$id'");   
                
    } else {
         $insert_player_query   = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO players (id,nickname,score,time_online,mapname,sid) VALUES ('$id','$player_nickname','$player_score','$player_time','$mapname','$server_id') WHERE id='$id'");   
    }
```

Comment: `uniqueid()` generates a string. When your ID field is numeric, it won't work.

Comment: And in this case what is to be done?

Comment: Make the ID field a varchar or char with fixed length, if your unique ID always having the same length.

Comment: I forgot to specify, I did this in the database.
 `id varchar (200) `
But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is this query correct?  "mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO players (id,nickname,score,time_online,mapname,sid) VALUES ('$id','$player_nickname','$player_score','$player_time','$mapname','$server_id') WHERE id='$id'");"

In my opinion the where contidion from the end is wrong

Comment: Your quotes are wrong. Check them over. Also use prepared statements to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: Option 2 won't work for updating, because you're still trying to use a new ID. You need to retrieve the ID from your SELECT query if it finds a matching row, and use that. And in there, your INSERT query doesn't need that WHERE on the end, as @PawełMiłosz said above.

Comment: Give me examples, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should check field and use:

```
CREATE TABLE `players` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nickname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_online` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mapname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO players (id,nickname,score,time_online,mapname,sid) VALUES ('1','player_nickname','1','1','mapname','1') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = score + VALUES(score), time_online = time_online + VALUES(time_online)
```

Please try it.

Comment: I added it to the base structure but nothing happened.

Comment: INSERT INTO player (id,nickname,score,time_online,mapname,sid) VALUES 
('$id','$player_nickname','$player_score','$player_time','$mapname','$server_id') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = score + VALUES(score), time_online = time_online + VALUES(time_online)

Comment: He duplicates it

Comment: id should not be auto-increment

Answer (score 0):

Remove "where" condition. It does not make any sense in "INSERT" statement.

Comment: I modified, but it inserts only 1 single player.

Comment: you need to use batch insert
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526917/how-to-do-a-batch-insert-in-mysql