# Efficient way to delete a large amount of records from a big table

Tags: mysql, performance

I want to delete a large amount of records (~200K) from a large table (~500K records) in my MySql DB.

I want to make this call as efficient as possible because i dont want the DB to become "unresponsive" while executing the call.
**I need to delete records that are "older" than 10 days** (according to `created_at` column), currently I use:

```
delete from table_name where created_at < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

The table also have a primary key `id` if it helps.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You may need to use a cursor / delete subsets of the data, so that you don't end up locking your database table (not sure how mysql handles this)

Comment: @forsvarir, cursors solve some problems but performance is never one of them.

Comment: How often are you planning on running these large deletes?

Comment: @Lieven: but unless I'm mistaken, they do help to address the issue of 'I don't want the DB to become unresponsive while executing the call'

Comment: @forsvarir: It could be made to work but you would be trading one large blocking call to many small blocking calls. A 500K table is not all that big these days. There should be no need to resort to such workarounds.

Comment: @Lieven: fair enough, once bitten, twice shy and all that... Obviously, it's going to depend where the DB is hosted, size of the records, and the frequency of other writes to the table as to whether or not there are collisions.  It takes 'a lot more than 2 seconds' (from below), to run, but it's unclear how long that is in real time, or if the DB being unresponsive has actually occured and is a problem.  I think it's an option to be aware of, but hopefully not need because you're right, it is a bit of a pain.

Comment: the call is performed twice a day but when i run it the DB became unresponsive for over 10 seconds (the records in the table are pretty large). wouldn't it be better to get the lowest id that matches the date criteria and delete everything below that id?

Comment: It depends why the database is locking up (I don't know much about mysql).  If the DB is locking because it's just too busy processing your update, then makeing the update easier to understand may make it process quicker.  I think there's enough data being changed that there's a possibility a full table/index lock is being put on, which will stop new rows being created in the table.  If this is the problem, then one way to get around it is to use a cursor that iterates the relevant rows, deleting and comitting in smaller batches.  You may want to try running explain plan against your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a WHERE condition, add an index on created_at field.

Comment: You could also use `DELETE LOW_PRIORITY`, which would help a little by waiting for the table to be unused (although by the look of things it doesn't interrupt the operation midway if someone starts reading/writing to the table).

Comment: `LOW_PRIORITY` has affects only storage engines that use only table-level locking (such as MyISAM, MEMORY, and MERGE).

Answer (score 15):

I was faced with the same challenge.
Having no primary key, but an index on the `created_at` field, it was not possible to delete the oldest 10Mio entries from a 100Mio row table (InnoDB). It constantly failed with lock overflows, due to the fact that the table is online and still receives INSERTS.

To solve the problem I created a stored procedure that tackled the job incrementally:

```
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE delete_accesslog_incrementally()
-> MODIFIES SQL DATA
-> BEGIN
-> REPEAT
-> DELETE FROM tbl_name
-> WHERE created_at < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 10 day)
-> LIMIT 20000;
-> UNTIL ROW_COUNT() = 0 END REPEAT;
-> END $$
```

This still runs quite a while, but doesn't harm the concurrent INSERTS that are still hitting the table.

Comment: how can we do for if we give inner query in where clause

Comment: Similar approach here http://www.rathishkumar.in/2017/12/deleting-huge-number-of-records-in-mysql.html

Answer (score 5):

You could try this:

1) First find the first id value for the desired date:

```
select id from table_name where created_at = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 10 DAY) LIMIT 1;
```

2) Next delete in batches:

```
DELETE FROM table_name where id<"id_found_on_step_1" LIMIT 1000;
```

On id_found_on_step_1 put the id value you found on step 1.
You can try 10000 or lower than 1000. It depends how much time every delete command will take.

This DELETE should be faster, since its WHERE statement uses the primary key.