# DELETE + JOIN + ORDER BY + LIMIT = syntax error

Tags: mysql, delete-row

Drop the `ORDER BY` + `LIMIT`, **or** the `JOIN`, and everything is peaches. Put them together and I seem to release the Kraken. Anyone who can shed some light?

```
DELETE table1 AS t1
FROM table1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.field = 'something'
ORDER BY t1.id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

([Delete using aliases](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/07/how-to-write-multi-table-cross-database-deletes-with-aliases-in-mysql/))

I've also tried it without aliases & dropping the `WHERE`, to no avail. Always a syntax error "`near 'ORDER BY...`".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From Mysql Docs: [**`DELETE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html)

> For the multiple-table syntax, DELETE deletes from each `tbl_name` the rows that satisfy the conditions. **In this case, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used**.

In your case, I think this works:

```
DELETE 
FROM table1
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT t2.id
        FROM table2 AS t2
        WHERE t2.id = table1.id
          AND t2.field = 'something'
      ) 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: So in layman's terms, I can have pie *or* cool whip, but not both. Blast.

Comment: See my update. A subquery with `IN` would work too. But usually `EXISTS` can be better optimized than an `IN` subquery in MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to do this you can do the following

```
DELETE table1 
WHERE id in
      (SELECT t.id
      FROM table1 AS t INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
      WHERE t2.field = 'something' --No point in doing a LEFT JOIN because of this
      ORDER BY t1.id DESC
       LIMIT 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

`t1` was not declared as an alias. Try `t` everywhere you have `t1` (or vice versa).