# mysql DELETE and limit

Tags: mysql, limit, sql-delete

I have a query that is working to display rows who contain specific meta key.

```
select wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.*
from wp_posts, wp_postmeta
inner join wp_woocommerce_order_items, wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
where wp_posts.post_type = "shop_subscription"
and wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
and wp_postmeta.meta_key = "_shipping_country"
and wp_postmeta.meta_value = "FR"
and wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = wp_posts.ID
and wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id
and wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = "_subtracted_base_location_taxes"
```

I want to delete these rows but with a limit. I ve got an error with this sql

```
DELETE wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.*
FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta
inner join wp_woocommerce_order_items, wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = "shop_subscription"
and wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
and wp_postmeta.meta_key = "_shipping_country"
and wp_postmeta.meta_value = "FR"
and wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = wp_posts.ID
and wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id
and wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = "_subtracted_base_location_taxes"
LIMIT 100
```

I have read that you can't use LIMIT directly within DELETE when you're referencing multiple tables at the same time. I begin with mysql and i am stuck. Any help would be apreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Try DELETE wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta  , removing dot and asterisk

Comment: @FranCerezo i tried your solution by removing dot and asterisk but same error from mysql #1064

Comment: @ProGu Thanks for your solution but as i said, i am too rookie to build this sort of query unfortunatly

Comment: @RG2022 :  wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta has any primary key ? and what is the primary key columns name ?

Comment: @AliFidanli 
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta (primary key is meta_id)
wp_woocommerce_order_items  (primary key is order_item_id)
wp_posts  (primary key is ID)
wp_postmeta  (primary key is  meta_id)

Comment: @RG2022 posted an answer -  it should work - couldnt test it since i dont have any fiddle to work on it

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
delete a
from wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta a
join (
  select wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_id
  from wp_posts, wp_postmeta
  inner join wp_woocommerce_order_items, wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
  where wp_posts.post_type = 'shop_subscription'
  and wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
  and wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_shipping_country'
  and wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'FR'
  and wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = wp_posts.ID
  and wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id
  and wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = '_subtracted_base_location_taxes'
  limit 100
) b on a.meta_id = b.meta_id
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! Work perfectly

Thanks for your time

Answer (score -1):

[mysql delete with inner joins and limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345180/mysql-delete-with-inner-joins-and-limit)