# MYSQL delete all data from table which have millions record with same name

Tags: mysql

Hi i want to delete all record of a table which have 10 millions record but its hang and give me follow error:

```
Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

I am using the following query:

```
delete from table where name = '' order by id limit 1000
```

in for loop.

Please suggest me how to optimize it.

Comment: If you want to delete all records, why do you have `order by id limit 1000` in there?

Answer (score 3):

You said `i want to delete all record of a table which have 10 millions record`. Then why not use `TRUNCATE` command instead which will have minimal/no overhead of logging.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tbl_name
```

You can as well use `DELETE` statement but in your case the condition checking (`where name = '' order by id limit 1000`) is not necessary since you wanted to get rid of all rows but `DELETE` has overhead of logging in transaction log which may matter for record volume of millions.

Per your comment, you have no other option rather than going by `delete from table1 where name = 'naresh'`. You can delete in chunks using the `LIMIT` operator like `delete from table1 where name = 'naresh' limit 1000`. So if `name='naresh'` matches 25000 rows, it will be deleting only 1000 rows out of them.

You can include the same in a loop as well like below (Not tested, minor tweak might require)

```
 DECLARE v1 INT;

 SELECT count(*) INTO v1 FROM table1 WHERE name = 'naresh';

  WHILE v1 > 0 DO
  DELETE FROM table1 WHERE name = 'naresh' LIMIT 1000;
    SET v1 = v1 - 1000;
  END WHILE;
```

So in the above code, loop will run for 25 times deleting 1000 rows each time (assuming `name='naresh'` condition returns 25K rows).

Comment: thanks for reply but i want do delete all record on the basis of name means where name='Rahul'

Comment: hi have seen the following link so i use this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318972/deleting-millions-of-rows-in-mysql

Comment: @naresh, then you have no other option rather than going by `delete from table1 where name = 'naresh'`

Comment: I know that but can you tell me how to get rid of this problem

Comment: @naresh, since you are trying to delete all rows matching a particular name; I don't think you really need `order by id limit 1000`. Remove that and just make it `delete from table1 where name = 'naresh'`. See how it goes.

Comment: I am try this which you said that but its also hang the DB

Comment: @naresh, one last suggestion I could give is: delete in chunks using the `LIMIT` operator like `delete from table1 where name = 'naresh' limit 1000`. So if `name='naresh'` matches 25000 rows, it will be deleting only 1000 rows out of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all records(empty table),
You can use

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `table_name_here`...
```

May be it will work for you...
(not tried with big database)

Comment: thanks for reply but i want do delete all record on the basis of name means where name='Shail'

Comment: You can use cron job Which will run every 1min(whatever time you set) and delete 100(any no of records) records every time....

Comment: @naresh So why does your question say something different? And your title say some different again?