# Using ActiveRecord find_in_batches method for deleting large data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Okay, so I know that when dealing with very large data, we can use `find_in_batches` which, as I understand it, does the work of `Model.all.each` in a really fast way which is much more efficient

Now, I have a really large data I'm trying to delete, and I'm thinking of using this same `find_in_batches` to delete them in batches.

below is what I have (from within the rake task `database.rake`):

```
old_messages = TextMessage.where("created_at < ?", number.days.ago )

old_messages.find_in_batches do |batch|
  batch.delete_all
end
```

When I run this however, I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..3)
/Users/Sunday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/httparty-0.13.5/lib/httparty.rb:66:in `logger'
/Users/Sunday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:94:in `public_send'
/Users/Sunday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:94:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/Sunday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:302:in `scoping'
/Users/Sunday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:94:in `method_missing'
/Users/Sunday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:112:in `find_in_batches'
/Users/Sunday/workspace/resilience/lib/tasks/database.rake:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

where `database.rake` on line 18 is: `old_messages.find_in_batches do |batch|`.

So, is it possible to use `find_in_batches` for deleting like I'm trying to do? and what am I doing wrong, if the answer to that is yes. Thanks for all response.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't think anyone has answered your question.

To answer 'what you are doing wrong' and can you use 'find_in_batches' in that way:

The reason why 'delete_all' does not work, is because 'delete_all' only works on activerecord relations. When you use 'find_in_batches' the variable 'batch' is now just a normal array, which may have it's own 'delete_all' method that is different,

You may need 'find_in_batches' incase if you have thousands of records to be deleted. So the previous answer is incorrect. (It may lead to memory exceeded exceptions and timeouts)

Note that is not related to the original error you displayed, but you cannot use 'batch' with 'delete_all' because 'batch' is an array and 'delete_all' is for activerecords

How to delete using find_in_batches

I was having a similar problem

```
user.posts.destroy_all
```

was overloading the server because of thousands of posts (this is an example my actual model was not 'posts')

You can use

```
user.posts.select(:id).find_in_batches(batch_size: 100) do |ids|
  Post.where(id: ids).delete_all
end
```

If it was one sql call, it will try to store all the delete items in memory at once that can break the server,
This will have a manageable size of sql calls.

Comment: Okay, you answered the question... to a point. Thank you... a follow up will be: when you use `find_in_batch`, how'll you go through deleting records in that batch?

Comment: Well this is how I found your post. I'll update my answer

Comment: `pluck` returns an array - you'll want to use select instead:

`User.posts.select(:id).find_in_batches`

Comment: when you have "a lot" I'm talking about millions, even 'select' is returning way too much info.

Answer (score 26):

New functionality: #in_batches (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-in_batches)

```
Person.where("age > 21").in_batches do |relation|
  relation.delete_all
end
```

Comment: why do you use this sleep in the process? Does it help somehow the database?

Comment: I guess that was my thinking - but for the life of me I can't remember.  I'm going to delete that line because... why...

Comment: The rails api docs on in_batches includes the sleep:   sleep(10) # Throttle the delete queries

Answer (score 3):

Use `Model.in_batches.destroy_all`.

Be mindful of `dependent` associations which might still be loaded without batching. I created a gem to fix this: [batch_dependent_associations](https://github.com/thisismydesign/batch_dependent_associations)

See also dhh's issue in Rails: [Relation#destroy_all should perform its work in batches](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22510)

Answer (score 2):

Using `in_batches` or `find_in_batches` with `delete_all`, like other answers suggest, will result in two queries per batch; one `SELECT` query to fetch the records and one `DELETE` query to delete the records.

A way to do batched deletes without fetching records could be:

```rb
def delete_batched(records, batch_size: 1000)
  loop do
    amount_deleted = records.reorder(:id).limit(batch_size).delete_all
    break if amount_deleted < batch_size
  end
end

delete_batched(TextMessage.where("created_at < ?", number.days.ago))
```

(It is my understanding that [a deterministic processing order is desirable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1318975) when doing deletes like this, hence the ordering by `:id`. Using `reorder` will replace any already set `order`)