# Deleting records with order by, limit in Spring hibernate throws InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to delete millions of rows in a MySQL table and it's failing with *SQLException - Connection is closed* exception if I tried to delete them all at once so as suggested in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1318975/5161239) decided to delete them in smaller chunks but I am getting spring InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException with this JPA native query

```
@Modifying
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "delete from customer where user_id = :userId ORDER BY id limit :limit")
int deleteByUserIdWithLimit(int userId, int limit);
```

it's working fine if I remove **ORDER BY id** in the above query. Is there any limitation to these types of queries in spring JPA?

Here is the stack trace:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [delete from customer where user_id = ? ORDER BY id limit ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:154)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.deleteByUserIdWithLimit(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.deleteByUserIdWithLimit(Unknown Source)
    at io.deletion.listener.repository.RepositoryTest.apiHistoryRepoTest(RepositoryTest.java:61)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "DELETE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE USER_ID = ? ORDER[*] BY ID LIMIT ?"; SQL statement: delete from customer where user_id = ? ORDER BY id limit ? [42000-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:229)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:1051)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:741)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "DELETE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE USER_ID = ? ORDER[*] BY ID LIMIT ?"; SQL statement: delete from customer where user_id = ? ORDER BY id limit ? [42000-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:229)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:1051)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:741)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
    ... 95 more
```

Comment: order by clause in delete SQL statement doesn't make sense.

Comment: @kingGarfield without ORDER BY records delete won't be deterministic; not doing so would have strange effects (including breaking replication in some cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to execute mySql query in h2 database. h2 does not support delete with order by. Try using a mysql database.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I thought the exception is comming from spring framework itself before querying the DB