# Delete query from million rows table with limit in my sql

Tags: mysql

I have created query to delete rows from million rows table in my sql. the query is given below,

```
DELETE N
FROM table_a N 
INNER JOIN table_b E ON N.form_id = E.form_id 
                     AND N.element_id = E.element_id 
                     AND E.element_type IN('checkbox','radio','select')
WHERE N.option_value = 0
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1000;
```

When executing the above query. gets error.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1000' at line 7
```

How to fix this issue. I have used the reference [Deleting millions of rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318972/deleting-millions-of-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: note only the [single table DELETE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html) has `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's multi-table DELETE syntax doesn't allow LIMIT. But you can use more conditions in the WHERE clause:

```
DELETE N
FROM table_a N 
INNER JOIN table_b E ON N.form_id = E.form_id 
                     AND N.element_id = E.element_id 
                     AND E.element_type IN('checkbox','radio','select')
WHERE N.option_value = 0
  AND N.id BETWEEN 1 AND 1000;
```

This might of course delete fewer than 1000, if there are gaps such that not all values of `N.id` are used. But at least it won't delete *more* than 1000 rows (assuming `id` is a unique key).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i have tried with the above query. but getting error. error=> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY N.id' at line 8

Comment: Then remove the ORDER BY clause. It also must not be allowed when using multi-table DELETE. If you're specifying a range of `id` then it isn't needed anyway. I'll edit my answer above and remove the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Thank you ..................                                               .